# usb - Ubuntu 18.04.3 doesn't recognize WD external hard drive on TOSHIBA SATTELITE

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive

`erik@erik-SATELLITE-C70D-B:~$ dmesg | tail -n 10
[28631.854016] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       10EAVS External  1.75 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[28631.856857] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[28631.858969] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[28631.860479] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[28631.860484] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[28631.862897] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[28631.862901] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[28631.891579]  sdb: sdb1
[28631.894732] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[32382.475451] gnome-control-c[19228]: segfault at 40000002 ip 0000563115e7ee75 sp 00007ffeadbfba90 error 4 in gnome-control-center[563115de7000+44c000]`

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect the drive. Once connected, `sudo lsblk -f`.

Comment: After sudo journalctl -- follow, the terminal has been working for 15 hours, and its still working. But for about an hour ago it came out with: Mounted /dev/sdd1 (Read-Write, label "WD Elements", NTFS 3.1)
- and then the WD Elements appeard in NAUTILUS, and I coud start working in it. YES!

Comment: Some code accessed the property 'WindowPreviewMenuItem' on the module 'windowPreview'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
What can í do by this?

Comment: After a night WD Elements had disappeard again! I try sudo lsbl, and uppdate + reboot.